# Azure ToDoList sample sync returns internal server error

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

**Update:**
This is resolved.  It turns out that the easy table only works with node.js backend.  When I publish my own .Net backend and have my own tables on the sql server, everything works.

I am just trying out the todo list example from the azure app service quick start (i used the provided node.js to create table API.  It builds fine and everything.  However, when I try to run the winApp simulator, it gives me 500 internal server error.  I also use the same example in xamarin studio to run in ios but receive the same error message.  I don't know why a sample doesn't work.  Please help!

Below is the message from azure application logs:

017-05-08T19:45:22  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
2017-05-08T19:46:22  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).

#### HTTP Error 500.1001 - Internal Server Error

The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Most likely causes:

- IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
- IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
- IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
- The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
- The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Things you can try:

- Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
- Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
- Verify the permissions for the DLL.
- Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
- Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439).

Detailed Error Information:

Module iisnode Notification ExecuteRequestHandler Handler iisnodeError Code 0x00000002

Requested URL https://ReadyNow:80/app.js?$filter=not(complete)&$filter=not(complete)

Physical Path D:\home\site\wwwroot\app.js

Logon Method Anonymous Logon User Anonymous

More Information:

This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.

Comment: a 500 is a server error.  You need to look at your server logs to determine what the actual error is

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the Node.js backend on Azure, we can first create an `IISNode.yml` file at the root of our Node.js application, and then add the following to it.

```
loggingEnabled: true
logDirectory: iisnode
```

The two steps mentioned above attempt to enable the logging of `stdout` and `stderr` streams, and create `iisnode` directory at the root of our app and log in the file there. 
See [How to debug a Node.js web app in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-nodejs-debug) for more details.

---

According to your application logs, the Requested URL is not correct. We can not directly access `app.js` in URL, instead, we should request the route that Node.js app provided. Since you've set up the Easy Tables properly, you could access the table with the endpoints listed in the [blog post](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/27/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-13-the-http-table-interface/).